# Error when launching a VB.Net Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Why does my app compiled with VB.NET not work on other computers?
It works only on the computer where Visual Studio 2012 is already installed.
I have the `.NET Framework 4.5` already installed.
This error appear when i try to execute the application:

```
CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   auto pc clean.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   547c1c02
Problem Signature 04:   Auto PC Clean
Problem Signature 05:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   547c1c02
Problem Signature 07:   27
Problem Signature 08:   ea
Problem Signature 09:   System.InvalidOperationException
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: That sounds like a problem with one or more .NET framework packages. Try to determine which framework versions are installed on the computer, and reinstall/install where necessary.

Comment: Ensure you are compiling with `x86` instead of `Any CPU`. Some of the `OCX` .NET modules have difficulty executing on x64 CPUs if the program is built on x64 (and vice versa). ***Please debug your program in Visual Studio and provide us with where is crashes and the code from the function it crashes in.***

Comment: cybermonkey: i already try to compiling with x86 and it's the same error that appear.

Comment: Justin Ryan : for the versions of .NET frmawork, i have just one (.NET Framwork 4.5)

Comment: Did Some one find any solutions?